# How do I create a home Scroll view like Instagram?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a home scroll, inside it, is a UIView that contains 2 UIImage, 2 UILabel and 2 UIButton. I was trying to copy the entire view and paste it above the copied UIView and so on. 
I was trying to do it with this:

`NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.contentView];
UIView *newView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
[self.homeScroll addSubview:newView];`

It apparently copy paste it correctly but my problem is that I want the newView duplicate stay one above each other. I was trying to position them like:

```
newView.center = CGPointMake(0.0, screenRect.size.height * i);
```

and

```
frame.origin.x = 0; // new x coordinate
frame.origin.y = screenRect.size.height * i; // new y coordinate
newView.frame = frame;
```

and

```
newView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height * i, self.homeScroll.frame.size.width, self.homeScroll.frame.size.height);
```

But without success.In all cases `i` is the typical `int i` variable of a for loop that run a requested object from a web service. And `screenRect.size.height` is the actual device screen height obtained from here `CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`. I increased the height of the UIScroll view like this:

```
CGSize newFrame = (CGSize){0 , screenRect.size.height * numberOfItems};
[self.homeScroll setContentSize:newFrame];
```

And works as expected.

I 've read About **Collection View** but it does not seems to be the solution.

**Here is a Screen Shot.**
[image]

Comment: I don't use Instagram, do you have a Screenshot or more explanation on what it looks like and what you want exactly to do? A animation of Instragram could be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "Home scroll"? Instagram is pretty much just a tableview(The main parts of it)

Comment: So with a custom uitableview I can solve it?